# In Apigility, how do I access a DELETE request's body content

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I am building an API with Apigility. I am tied to a backend, where deleting a resource requires additional data, not just the resource ID taken from the URL. So I need to read a parameter fom a DELETE request's body.

While in POST request's `create()` method I can simply access the $data parameter, this does not work with DELETE methods, because only `$id` is provided.

Accessing `$this->getEvent()->getRequest();` in my Resource classes' `delete()` method, I see the request's body content (form-data) wrapped into a property called 'content' - as a string.

Can someone point me at what I am missing to access the body's key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apigility does not expect any data to be passed to a `DELETE` request, so it does not pass it to the event params. You can just retrieve it from the request as you discovered and do the json_decode yourself.

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $body = $this->getEvent()->getRequest()->getContent();
    $data = json_decode($body, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately `$body` is not valid JSON but a string like the following, `var_dump()`ed:

`string '------WebKitFormBoundaryltcFOyHq6kVAGS1X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_type"

android
------WebKitFormBoundaryltcFOyHq6kVAGS1X--
' (length=149)`

I am using Postman to send the DELETE request, using its form-data fields.

Comment: Problem solved: the solution was in Postman to set the header `Content_type: application/json` and send the request with raw body, containing the JSON string, e.g. `{ "device_type": "android" }`. This way the above solution works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot upvote the answer due to a lack of reputation, alas.